# stop termination of pyspark stream when testing

Tags: python, pyspark, pytest

I have a PySpark stream that reads from Kafka, and writes to an Apache Hudi table, for example

```py
def write_batch_to_hudi(batch_df, batch_id):
    new_df = here_im_getting_new_df(batch_df)
    write_to_hudi(new_df)
    

def stream(spark):
    df = read_stream_from_kafka(spark)

    df \
        .writeStream \
        .foreachBatch(write_batch_to_hudi) \
        .start() \
        .awaitTermination()
```

And I want to test it all end to end, so I mock the `read_stream_from_kafka` function to read from some Json files, and the `write_to_hudi` to do nothing

```py
def test_stream(mock_spark, mock_read_stream_from_kafka, mock_write_to_hudi):
    stream(mock_spark)
```

But when I run the `test_stream`, it never ends because of the `.awaitTermination()` statement, but how can I make sure that after I run all files given in `mock_read_stream_from_kafka`, the test will terminate?

Comment: show your fixture definitions

Answer (score 0):

Try using trigger once as explained in the [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#triggers) and in this [thread](https://community.databricks.com/s/question/0D53f00001GHVO6CAP/triggeronce-mode-recommendation)